# Issues with the stem function of MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-hg2

I've installed the last version of MATLAB R2014b, I have a problem with the stem function not showing the line to the Data points , for example:

```
stem(1:12);
```

looks like [image: this]

I've try to adjust the Linestyle as shown in documentation .

```
figure
X = linspace(0,2*pi,25)';
Y = (cos(2*X));
stem(X,Y,'LineStyle','-.',...
     'MarkerFaceColor','red',...
     'MarkerEdgeColor','green')
```

but it didn't help, any idea what's the problem here ?

**UPDATE**
after running

```
h= stem(1:12)
get(h)
```

here is the output :

```
  Annotation: [1x1 matlab.graphics.eventdata.Annotation]
          BaseLine: [1x1 Baseline]
         BaseValue: 0
      BeingDeleted: 'off'
        BusyAction: 'queue'
     ButtonDownFcn: ''
          Children: []
          Clipping: 'on'
             Color: [0 0.4470 0.7410]
         CreateFcn: ''
         DeleteFcn: ''
       DisplayName: ''
  HandleVisibility: 'on'
           HitTest: 'on'
     Interruptible: 'on'
         LineStyle: '-'
         LineWidth: 0.5000
            Marker: 'o'
   MarkerEdgeColor: 'auto'
   MarkerFaceColor: 'none'
        MarkerSize: 6
            Parent: [1x1 Axes]
     PickableParts: 'visible'
          Selected: 'off'
SelectionHighlight: 'on'
      ShowBaseLine: 'on'
               Tag: ''
              Type: 'stem'
     UIContextMenu: []
          UserData: []
           Visible: 'on'
             XData: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]
         XDataMode: 'auto'
       XDataSource: ''
             YData: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]
       YDataSource: ''
             ZData: [1x0 double]
       ZDataSource: ''
```

Comment: Bizarre. Can you do `h = stem(1:12)` and then check `get(h)`? Do other line plots work?

Comment: I'm reinstalling R2014b , I'll write update the answer when the installation is done !

Comment: @nkjt here please check the update of my question

Comment: @Engine My Matlab 2014b does the lines with just `stem(x)`

Comment: @Ander sorry I don't get what you mean , I wrote an example of stem(1:12) and the result still the same, even after reinstalling MATLAB R2014b

Comment: @Engine I mean that it works for me in Matlab2014b if i do `stem(1:12)`, so the problem has to be in your machine, not in Matlab itself.

Comment: I'm using win7 64bit

Comment: I don't get what's the problem :/

Comment: @Engine Neither do I. It just looks like you are the only one (or not, who knows) that has that problem. It is not a functionality/bug of Matlab 2014b,  as it works perfectly in my machine. Hope you can fix it.

Comment: @Engine Did you solve this issue? It's working perfectly here with MATLAB R2014b and Windows 7 64bit. What is the output of `which stem`?

Comment: I got the new version of MATLAB it works fine I think it'S a bug or smt similar

Comment: On 2015A I do get the stem with exactly the same properties as your stem. You don't accidentally call a figure command after stem or something?